# "this" keyword with Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, this, prototype

I'm confused with the "this"keyword in JS. I understand that rabbit's prototype is animal and the "this" keyword in `rabbit.isSleeping` should refer to rabbit but I thought the `animal.isSleeping` should refer to animal I don't understand why it's undefined? Could someone explain?

```
let animal = {
  walk() {
    if (!this.isSleeping) {
      alert(`I walk`);
    }
  },
  sleep() {
    this.isSleeping = true;
  }
};

let rabbit = {
  name: "White Rabbit",
  __proto__: animal
};


rabbit.sleep();

alert(rabbit.isSleeping); // true
alert(animal.isSleeping)
```

Comment: `animal` has no `isSleeping` property. Its properties are `walk` and `sleep`.

Comment: Don't use `__proto__` directly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @trincot it does if you call `sleep`

Comment: @Daniel, but that is not happening, is it? Of course, it will also have it when you do `animal.isSleeping = true`, but what does that have to do with the question?

Answer (score 2):

When a property is assigned to an object - here, when you do

`this.isSleeping = true;`

The engine will first examine the instance, then its internal prototype, and so on up to the beginning of the prototype chain - to identify the first such object that has an `isSleeping` property. If an object is found, and it's a setter, the setter is invoked. Otherwise, no matter where the property is found, the *instance* is assigned the property (as a data property, of course).

When you do

```
rabbit.sleep();
```

the instance is `rabbit` - that's the `this` inside the method. And there are no `isSleeping` setters, so

```
  sleep() {
    this.isSleeping = true;
  }
```

results in the instance - the `rabbit` object - receiving the property. So the `animal` object remains unchanged.

Unless there are getters/setters involved somewhere, doing

```
someObj.someProp = someVal
```

will *always* and only ever result in `someObj` being mutated, while keeping its internal prototype(s) unchanged.

Comment: Thx for your explanation. how come animal.isSleeping return undefined? Do we go to the Object.prototype of the prototype chain?

Comment: The property exists on `rabbit` not an `animal`, and `rabbit` is not in `animal`'s prototype chain, so `animal.isSleeping` gives undefined. It only exists on `rabbit` - you have to check it there.

Comment: @javalol `rabbit.sleep()` is the same thing as `rabbit.isSleeping = true;`. At no point, `animal.isSleeping` is written to, and since it's not been defined in your code, it's `undefined`.